# How to catch didFinishLaunchingWithOptions inside Unity script

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I need to initialise one specific iOS framework inside `UIApplicationDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method - this is critical. Moreover I need to make it from Unity object. I tried `Awake()` method of `MonoBehaviour` but it seems like it invokes after `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. I learned Unity documentation and found nothing similar. Does anybody know if it is possible at all? May be any workaround?

Comment: You could try to call UnitySendMessage from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html. You should explain a bit more the data you need and where from.

Comment: yeah, I understand what you mean, and it would probably worked, but unfortunately not acceptable in my case as I'm developing iOS plugin and can not change UIApplicationDelegate.mm generated by unity. the plugin is supposed to be distributed to 3rd party developers.

Comment: UIApplicationDelegate is a protocol, somehow kinda like an interface. All this does is that the application is looking for UIApplicationDelegate to be called when UIApplication does a specific action. Now, long story short, you can create your own class implementing UIApplicationDelegate protocol.